# Determining which voltage is higher in nodal Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

Im trying to learn nodal analysis.In the below example  why do you subtract Vb from Va and not the opposite? ///y for Vc and Vb?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from what has already been mentioned in the other answer, when figuring out the voltage across a component, follow the direction of the current. So in your case, I1 is going from Va to Vb. So the voltage across the 10 ohm resistor is Va - Vb. Similarily, I2 is going from Vc to Vb, so the voltage across the 20 ohm resistor is Vc - Vb. I3 goes from Vb to ground, hence the voltage across 40 ohm resistor is just Vb. Now, given these voltages, they are simply applying KCL.

Comment: Remember to up vote answers so other users know which one is reliable.

Comment: I had tried,I can't i need minimum 15 rep to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

The nodal analysis is just the KCL we are used to. First, you need to use a convention. For example, always sum the currents entering the node and equate them to zero. In your case, Va-Vb/10 is the current that is going into the node b. And so on.

Comment: Va and Vb are voltages..right?

Comment: Yep, they are voltages at the node a and b respectively. So Va-Vb/10 indicates the current flowing from a to b, while Vb-Va/10 is the opposite, meaning the current that is flowing to the left which is negative of the one flowing to the right.